# using wif with web api

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I got lots of articles and SO question based on Claim based authentication for WCF Restful Services, but I am using MVC Web API to develop RESTful Service (Not WCF Rest Service)...

So could you please help me to understand how to secure RESTful service using claim based authentication?

Here is what I need:

1. I have a Web App and MVC4 Web-API service
2. We have STS
3. The MVC Web App trusts the STS
4. Now the user logs into the Web App, he is redirected to the STS login page.
5. Once logged in, he is redirected back to the MVC Web Site.
6. This web app invokes the web-API Service.

Now, I have been stuck at point #4. We have a RESTful service, but need to implement WIF.

Can anyone please help me with this.

**Note:** I am NOT using WCF Restservice but using MVC Web API

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you are using a delegated identity model. That is, the user signs in to the web application and when the web application invokes the Web API service, it uses the identity of the currently logged in user.

If that is the case, then you need to configure WIF to save the "bootstrap tokens". The effect of this is that the original security token is available as a property on the current ClaimsIdentity. you can then use that to set the Authorize header of he request to the Web API service call.

To turn this on in .Net 4.5 you set the saveBootstrapContext attribute on the WIF  element to true:

```
<system.identityModel>
   <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
   ...
```

For .Net 4, the config looks lke this:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
   <service saveBootstrapTokens="true">
   ...
```

Then to access it from the web application you do something like (depending on how many identities you have) this in the controller that is going to call the Web API. For .Net 4.5:

```
SecurityToken token = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).Identities[0].BootstrapContext;
```

For .Net 4:

```
SecurityToken token = (User as ClaimsPrincipal).Identities[0].BootstrapToken;
```

Having obtained the original security token, you can now attach it to the calls to the Web API as an Authorize header. Generally this will be attached as a Bearer token, which is just a fancy way of saying that you append the word "bearer" to the start of the header value. To attach the token, do something like this:

```
WebClient request = new WebClient();
request.Headers.Add("Authorization","bearer " + tokenAsString);
```

**Note:** Generally you will encrypt or base64 encode the token value in transit rather than attach the raw string, especially if it is XML, since some frameworks will mangle the XML in transit.

To convert the token to a string, you should user a class derived from  `SecurityTokenHandler` There are a number of these included in the standard framework assemblies for handling some standard token types. For REST services, the JSON Web Token is a popular format and there is a NuGet package containing a handler for that here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

If you are using some other token type, you can write your own handler (it is not difficult in fact) or try to find on on the web.

In .Net 4.5 the `SecurityTokenHandler` class has a `WriteToken(SecurityToken)` method that returns the token as a string. In earlier versions of WIF only the XML version of WriteToken was supported.

There are several samples showing how to use the SecurityTokenHandler for REST services on the server side. A good example is here

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Native-App-to-REST-de57f2cc/view/Discussions#content

All the relevant code is contained in the global.asax.cs file.

Comment: how to attach it and call WEB API.....could you provide an example .... or sample code?

Comment: could you please also provide an example of calling the same using JavaScript (how can we attach token in this case), also from your reply it is not clear what should be the config/code at service side.....?

Comment: also at service end how to see the elements of claimset like emailid, userid etc....which is usually being added by sts while generating claims.....

Comment: Are you calling the STS explicitly from the browser using javascript? I would expect to do the initial web application sign in using WS-Federation Passive Profile, and then make the onward service call from the server, using the bootstrap context. If you are not doing this, then my answer might not be right for you...

Comment: I am calling STS explicitly...my web app config is having microsoft.identitymodel section which redirects to sts and after that token is sent back to web app which actually make calls to service

Comment: yes  like you said, I am using a delegated identity model, where the user signs in to the web application and when the web application invokes the Web API service, it uses the identity of the currently logged in user.....

Comment: As with most things around WIF, this example makes a jump that I cannot follow. First, "tokenAsString" is really giving me trouble in that I can't find a good way to serialize the token properly. Second, what are you doing in the web api service to receive the base64-encoded token? Is there more manual activity on the service to handle the token?

Comment: @MarkAJohnson: I added some extra guidance on how to serialise tokens and a link on how to use them from a REST service.

Comment: See my answer here about base64 stuff : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000244/pass-saml-token-into-web-api-call/33006036#33006036

Answer (score 1):

If your client is not authenticated the your Web Api service should return a 401 Unauthorized response.

It will then be your clients responsibly to seek authentication and gain a new token. You should return the link to your log in form in the WWW-authenticate header

This video might help - Securing ASP.NET Web APIs http://vimeo.com/43603474

Comment: I had already gone through the link you had provided ....but I cannot use any other framework ....as we have sts , rest service & web app in place ....we just need to play around these to get it done....may be using microsoft identity model